# How do I vertically align a div inside a table cell?

Tags: html, css, html-table, vertical-alignment

How do I vertically center a div that is inside a table cell?

HTML:

```
<tr class="rowClass">
    <td class="cellClass">
        <div class="divClass">Stuff</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
.rowClass {
    vertical-align:middle !important;
    height:90px;
}

.cellClass {
    vertical-align:middle !important;
    height:90px;
}

.divClass {
    vertical-align:middle !important;
    height:90px;
}
```

I know the class definitions are redundant, but I've been trying lots of different things. Why isn't the solution (whatever it is) intuitive. None of the "obvious" solutions that I tried would work.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is no need to define`height` in **.divClass** . write like this:

```
.cellClass {
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:90px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/ncrKH/

Comment: Thanks! I had `float:left` which screwed everything up.

Comment: Yes, float & display:block effect table functionality.

Answer (score -1):

`.divClass {
    margin-top:auto;
}`

**HTML**

```
<table border=1>
<tr class="rowClass">
<td class="cellClass">
    <div class="divClass">Stuff</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.rowClass {
vertical-align:middle !important;
height:90px;
}

.cellClass {
vertical-align:middle !important;
height:90px;
}

.divClass {
margin-top:auto; 
 }​
```

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/P3QVT/1/)

Comment: Put the contents of your Fiddle into your answer here, and explain what the code does.  See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231

Answer (score -1):

With out any css itself you can do this with `valign="middle"` try this code.

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <th height="550" align="center" valign="middle" scope="col">

    <div>Hello</div>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `valign` is not supported in HTML5